# Node.js Request - Can't get properties of REST Response (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have some JSON returned from an HTTP endpoint in the Node.js [Request](https://github.com/request/request) package. The `body` of the response is a JSON object with the following (`Content-Type` of `application/json`) :

```
{
    exchange_rate: 1.0,
    format: {
        symbol: '$',
        precision: 2,
        thousands_separator: ',',
        decimal_separator: '.'
    }
}
```

When I use `console.log(body);` I get the following (it's verbatim to the above):

```
{
    exchange_rate: 1.0,
    format: {
        symbol: '$',
        precision: 2,
        thousands_separator: ',',
        decimal_separator: '.'
    }
}
```

However, when I try to access the `exchange_rate` value, it returns `undefined`:

```
console.log(body.exchange_rate);
```

I tried to use `JSON.parse(body);` however it fails because it's already JSON:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
    at Object.parse (native)
    ...
```

Any idea how I can access the individual properties of this JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that what you have is **not** JSON.

Property names in JSON must be represented by *strings*, not identifiers. Strings must be quoted using `"` characters and not `'`.

You are getting the `Unexpected token e` error because you have an `e` where you should have a `"`.

If you had had a JavaScript object (i.e. had successfully parsed the "JSON") you would get `Unexpected token o` (o not e) because it would have stringified to `[object Object]`.

Comment: Awesome response, thank you! I'll give this a shot. Definitely learned something here at least.

Comment: As it turns out, this was exactly what I needed. Thanks very much for taking the time to answer!